# How to get the total of Weee Tax in Magento Order Grid

Tags: php, magento

I need to charge our customers with an additional environmental tax within our Magento webshop. After some reading on the web, I understood I needed to add a new attribute of the Fixed Product Tax type.

I've done that and managed to inform our customers about this additional tax on their invoice, so they know what their contribution is.

So far so good.

But more important is that I should be able to see what the total of this tax is for a specific order in total. Is there a way to accomplish this? Apparently this value isn't separately saved in the sales_flat_order table of Magento. Ideally situation would be that I could see this total amount on the Order Grid in Magento. I know how I can add additional columns on this order grid, but I'm struggling to find a way how I could achieve the total value of this FPT attribute.

Anyone has an idea?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem myself. For future notice I'll pen down how I accomplished it.

The total of weee tax per item row is found in the table sales_flat_order_item, so I practically did a table join to have access to this data on the Order Grid.

I created my own version of the Grid.php (located at app\code\local\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Order\Grid.php) and have overridden the _prepareCollection() method.

```
 protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
        $collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order_item', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_item.order_id', array('SUM(weee_tax_applied_row_amount) as totalrecupel') );               
        $collection->getSelect()->group('main_table.entity_id');            
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

In the _prepareColumns() method I added the new column.

```
$this->addColumn('totalrecupel', array(
                'header' => $this->__('Recupel Contribution'),
                'width' => '100px',
                'index' => 'totalrecupel',
                'type' => 'currency',
                'currency' => 'order_currency_code' 
            )
        );
```

Hope someone else finds this useful! ;-)